# How can I check if a command behind a C++ pipe is still running on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, process, pipe

On Windows, consider this:

```cpp
FILE* pipe = _popen("ping -w 999999 8.8.8.7", "r");
```

How can I tell if the command run by `_popen` is still running?

- If it *has* terminated, that is easy: `fgetc` will fail and set the EOF flag - `feof` will tell me the pipe has been closed.
- But if it has *not* terminated, `fgetc` will block and EOF will not be set.

In this latter situation, how do I check if the command has terminated? (Remember, this is on Windows.)

Comment: On a POSIX system, you could do that with `poll` and check for `POLLHUP`. Does Windows have a `_poll` function to go along with `_popen`?

Comment: @Wintermute not that I am aware of, unfortunately. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/aspnet/en-US/d6eef2f3-5292-476c-9e63-4951b22ae922/is-there-a-poll-equivalent-for-pipes-in-windows-just-as-we-have-wsapoll-for-sockets-in-windows?forum=windowssdk

Comment: That's probably why I've never seen _popen() used in Windows.